# Typing `fglrxinfo` command outputs "Command not found" on 12.04

Tags: command-line, graphics, system-info

I have a simple question and I do not know if the answer is around, but I did not find it. My question is "why whenever I type `fglrxinfo` in the terminal its says `command not found` and when I was on Ubuntu 11.10 It was working correctly.

Comment: Did you change videocard in between? ;) Or did you not install the graphics driver yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `fglrx` package to do this command.
Open the terminal, and issue this command
`sudo apt-get install fglrx`

Answer (score 0):

`fglrxinfo` is associated with ATI/AMD graphics driver. You need to install ATI binary X.Org driver from ubuntu software center.